# "For no other reason than" vs. "for no other reason that" vs. "for no other reason than that"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, prepositions, conjunctions

I am looking for a comprehensive analysis of these three constructions:

> 1. ... for no other reason than X.
> 2. ... for no other reason that X.
> 3. ... for no other reason than that X.

Which is used when? Is this a question of register, dialect, style? How does the usage depend on what X is? Which of the constructions is the oldest, and what is the linguistic reasoning behind the other two variations coming about and happily co-existing — reanalysis, corruption, eggcorning?

I searched the Language Log, but to no avail. Google is of no real help, either — it returns few promising results, which upon closer examination turn out to be unrelated to the question at hand.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that

> For no other reason than

takes a nominal complement, and if what follows is a NP (eg *your intransigence*) it is simply used.

When the complement is a clause, it needs the complementiser "that", (eg *that I want to*)

Your number 2, on the face of it, makes no sense to me, but I would be quite prepared to believe that people say it for number 3.

Comment: Well, if we can replace X with anything at all, (2) could be *valid for no other reason **that** I can think of*. The other two seem to be exactly as you say.

Comment: Yes, but that _that_ is simply a relative pronoun, and not in construction with _no other reason_; one could use either _which_, or Zero, instead.